# CSS animation not smoothly in Firefox

Tags: css

I have this simple loading indicator

https://jsfiddle.net/tcdLj0f9/

```css
body {
  background: #1e263e;
}

.load {  
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.loadersp {
    border: 12px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top: 12px solid #555!important;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 96px;
    height:96px;
    animation: sp-rotate 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes sp-rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn)
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="load">
  <div class="loadersp"></div>
</div>
```

It works smoothly in Chrome whereas not in Firefox(using latest).. even looking at the edges of the spinner as you can see they are rough, why that? I know they use different rendering engines but I didn't expect such thing to happen.

So is there a way to fix for it?

Comment: Have your tried this outside the jsfiddle? I can confirm the slow behaviour in jsfiddle and also tried this on codepen - it's the same. Tried with prefixes and will-change - the same. But running it locally doesn't show any signs chunky behaviour. I suppose it has something to do with animation running in iframe in firefox?

Comment: did you try `360deg` instead of `1turn`?

Comment: Looks like a JSFiddle issue. Strange though. Keep moving the mouse pointer in the output section and the transition changes to smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Firefox bug.

If you're using animation in `position:fixed` container within `iframe` (like jsfiddle or SO snippet) it runs choppy in Firefox. Out of `iframe` it works smoothly.

Removing `position:fixed` fixes it in `iframe`:

```css
body {
  background: #1e263e;
}

.load {
  display: flex;
  /* position: fixed; */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.loadersp {
  border: 12px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 12px solid #555 !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  animation: sp-rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes sp-rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="load">
  <div class="loadersp"></div>
</div>
```